# AWS Lambda (python 3.6) – creating text with hyperlink

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, hyperlink

I will use my Lambda for sending email notifications via SES and in the body of email I would like to create a hyperlink.

Example email body:

Please go to doc <- where after clicking on the word “Guide doc” I would have a link like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I was trying to create something like this ->  {Guideline doc}  but I'm geting syntax error don’t know how to show this in the text as a name of some document etc.

I would also need to create a HTML Table in the email body but I don’t know if this is possible in aws Lambda.

Example:

```
import json

import boto3

import csv

from datetime import datetime

 

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for i in event['Records']:

        bucket_name = i['s3']['bucket']['name']

        object = i['s3']['object']['key']

        s3=boto3.client('s3')

        response=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=object)

        csv_contents = response['Body'].read()

        csv_contents_decoded = csv_contents.decode('utf-8')

        reader=csv.reader(csv_contents_decoded.splitlines())

        print('type csv_contents_decoded:',type(csv_contents_decoded))

        print('type reader:',type(reader))

        print('csv_contents_decoded:',csv_contents_decoded)

        print('reader:',reader)

       

        

        currentMonth = datetime.now().month

        currentYear = datetime.now().year

        previousMonth = currentMonth-1

       

        owner_list = []

        sponsor_list = []

        for row in reader:

            owner_list.append(row[1]+'@example.com')

            sponsor_list.append(row[2]+'@example.com')

       

        

            

            

        

        

    client = boto3.client('ses')

    subject = 'Test'

    body = f'''

         <br>

         Test

         {previousMonth} is in {currentYear}.

         Text with hyperlink and html table.

 

        

        

         

    '''

        

    message = {'Subject': {'Data': subject}, 'Body': {'Html': {'Data': body}}}

    response = client.send_email(Source = 'test@domain.dev', Destination = {'ToAddresses': owner_list 'CcAddresses': sponsor_list},Message=message)   

        

    # TODO implement

    return {

        'statusCode': 200,

        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')

    }
```

I would appreciate your advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you use to send the message and also the error you're getting?

Comment: I would like to have in the body text, hyperlink and html table as part of one email body. So text with let's say 10 hyperlinks and one html table, all in one body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
from datetime import datetime
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for i in event['Records']:
        bucket_name = i['s3']['bucket']['name']
        object = i['s3']['object']['key']
        s3=boto3.client('s3')
        response=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=object)
        csv_contents = response['Body'].read()
        csv_contents_decoded = csv_contents.decode('utf-8')
        reader=csv.reader(csv_contents_decoded.splitlines())
        print('type csv_contents_decoded:',type(csv_contents_decoded))
        print('type reader:',type(reader))
        print('csv_contents_decoded:',csv_contents_decoded)
        print('reader:',reader)
        
        
        currentYear = datetime.now().year
        curryear = int(str(currentYear)[-2:])
        months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        current_month = datetime.now().month -1
        current_mnth = [months[(current_month)]]
        curr_mnth = ''.join(current_mnth)
        previous_mnth = [months[(current_month)-1]]
        prev_mnth = ''.join(previous_mnth)
        
        to_list = []
        cc_list = []
        for row in reader:
            to_list.append(row[1]+'@example.com')
            cc_list.append(row[2]+'@example.com')
        
            
            
        
        
    client = boto3.client('ses')
    subject = f'''[Update reminder] for {prev_mnth}'{curryear}'''
    table = """
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding: 15px;}
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>text...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
    ...
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    body = f'''
         <br>
         text...,<br>
        
         {table}
         <br>
         Thank you...
 
    '''
 
    message = {'Subject': {'Data': subject}, 'Body': {'Html': {'Data': body}}}
    response = client.send_email(Source = 'example@example.com', Destination = {'ToAddresses': to_list},Message=message)    
        
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Send an email using the AWS SDK for Python (Boto)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html) example from the AWS Developer Guide (adapted to your case, focus on `BODY_TEXT` and `BODY_HTML`):

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "Sender Name <sender@example.com>"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "recipient@example.com"

# Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
# set, comment the following variable, and the 
# ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

# If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"

# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)"

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = ("This is some regular text\r\n"
             "Please go to doc at the following link:"
             "http://www.example.com"
            )
            
# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>This is some regular text</p>
  <a href='http://www.example.com'>Please go to doc</a>
</body>
</html>
            """            

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

# Try to send the email.
try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Regarding the HTML table, the limit here is what HTML can do and most importantly what browsers/email clients you're targeting. An example of table would be:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can find a good reference of how HTML Tables work on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics).